# When writing a new theorem, is it acceptable to introduce some new definitions concepts?

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

Let's say I'm writing a new theorem but I need to introduce concepts, definitions and lemmas, of course valid, in my own way, since I don't know if someone defined them before in the past.

I am concerned that this may be inconvenient in making it public, losing legitimacy in the matter or infringing any copyright.

Comment: Have you ever looked at *any* math research paper whatsoever? This is not only allowed, but common and at least in some sense even desired! Introducing new notions, if it helps approach problems, can only bring more good.

Comment: There are many theorems which state lemmas that have been used before in other documents. I don't think one can claim ownership of such materials such as to infringe copyright.

Comment: What does copyright law have to do with defining terms in a math paper? Or perhaps a more correct wording of what I'm actually curious about is where did you get the idea that this would even be a concern?

Comment: In a nutshell, you can't copyright an idea, only the specific presentation of a paper.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I am not so worried about copyright, I am more concerned that something like this is interpreted as a low quality work. Suppose, a very rude example, in which I expose as a new motto the trigonometric inequality which I propose to call "curvature." It is possible that for things like this the text looks like a hoax; Not being that. Don´t you think so?

Comment: Regarding "low quality work", probably what you want to be on guard against is using already standard terminology for something different. Here google helps a lot. In the past I suspect the absence of being able to easily check this across very different fields is one reason for multiple terms for certain concepts, but it's certainly not the only reason --- see [math uses of normal here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal). Also try to avoid excessive use of terminology. Forcing readers to "learn a foreign language" just to scan over the results of your paper will result in no readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a definitive "yes", regarded that these definitions are not a rewording of existing ones or negating known facts. Also, new definitions must be justified and have direct relationship to the subject you present.

This recommendation is from [Writing a Research Paper in Mathematics - From an MIT professor](http://web.mit.edu/jrickert/www/mathadvice.html)

"In the second section of your paper, the introduction, you will begin to lead the reader into your work in particular, zooming in from the big picture towards your specific results. This is the place to introduce the definitions and lemmas which are standard in the field, but which your readers may not know."